# Describe filtering using math notoation

Tags: notation

s is defined as $s : {1,2,3}$

To describe the function that filters values great that $a$ where $a = 2$ and multiplies result by 4, is this correct :

$$ \sum_{s \in S} : [ s > a] \cdot 4$$

Comment: $\Sigma$ denotes a summation, which is not what you want I think. If I understand your question correctly then you want
$$\{s\in S\mid s>a\}$$

Comment: @user2520938 whats the | symbol ? why not use 'such that' instead ?

Comment: $\mid$ essentially means "such that". You don't use "such that" because its longer, and less readable. The notation I used above is completely standard. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation

Comment: @user2520938 that article also mentions using colon as alternative which is notation I'm more familiar with, thanks.

Comment: That notation is called an Iverson bracket (no hyperlink b/c phone). It evaluates a proposition inside to 1 if true and 0 if false. It can be used to filter items inside a sum, but it is more common to define a new set based on $S$ and sum over that.